# how to pass href attribute in jinja2?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I created Flask HTML template and I need to create an icon (fa-link) with a link to an external website so if user clicks the icon it will redirect him/her to external website.

[image]

The hardcoded version looks like this:

```
<h3 class="border-bottom mb-2 text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-link ml-3"></i></a></h3>
```

What I want is to use Jinja2 to generate variable and pass title and link to external website in my flask template file so something like this:

```
<h3 class="border-bottom mb-2 text-left">{% block product_title %}{% endblock %}<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-link ml-3"></i></a></h3>
```

And min my rendered html file I have:

```
{% block title %}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin
{% endblock %}
```

Could you please explain how to pass `href` attribute to rendered html?

Answer (score 1):

you can send href link directly from flask to html file like
Python Code:

```
return render_template("index.html", href = "https://www.google.com", title='google')
```

Html Code:

```
<a href="{{href}}">{{title}}</a>
```

Let me know if it didnt work, we'll figure this out.